# Searching for letters and updating data using sql

Tags: php, sql

Next code is looking for characters in an string from "note" column in all rows in a data table. 
   Once it gets  row "id", then it should update "did_read" column to value "1" in the  same row. But no success.  What corrections must I do to make it work?

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['str'])){ 

       $strid =$_POST['str'];
       $sql="SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE note CONTEINS='$strid'  ";
       $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
       $statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
       if($statusnumrows> 0){
       while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $statusid = $row["id"];
       $sql = "UPDATE notifications SET did_read='1' WHERE id='$statusid'";
       $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
       echo 'did_read_ok';
       exit;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Looking now I think that I should be much easier use next. But also is not working.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['str'])){ 

  $strid= mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['str']);

   $sql = "UPDATE notifications SET did_read='1' WHERE note LIKE='$strid' ";
   $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
   echo 'did_read_ok';
   exit;



}
?>
```

I have made some conclusions with your help down in comments. The First part of code is working  if I do uncomment it. But then I can't understand why other code in the condition loop is not working as I am getting "string(10)'status_218'" and "did_read_ok" ?  I am sending 'str' variable with ajax.send().

```
<?php
     //$strid= 'status_218';
     //  $sql = "UPDATE notifications SET did_read='1' WHERE note LIKE '%$strid%'";// not working:LIKE CONCAT('%', $strid, '%')
     //  $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

if (isset($_POST['str'])){ 
   $strid= $_POST['str'];
   var_dump($strid);//I get: string(10)status_218
   $sql = "UPDATE notifications SET did_read='1' WHERE note LIKE='%$strid%'";
   $query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
   echo 'did_read_ok';
   exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: which SQL dialect are you using? MSSQL has `CONTAINS`, whereas with mysql/mariadb you should use `LIKE`. Also, your query should be sanitized since it takes arguments straight from POST.

Comment: @onik SQL Server also has LIKE. And OP is using the mysqli connection interface, which means it's MySQL

Comment: While using the LIKE operator, you should also include the wildcard `%`, otherwise it's just as using =

Comment: @Qirel ah, true. So the query should be `SELECT id FROM notifications WHERE note LIKE '%$strid%'`

Comment: That's one thing - another is that one should always use a prepared statement. So the condition should be `WHERE note LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')` and then bind that placeholder to `$strid` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should not be answering this question, but I want to help you out. First of all you must enable error reporting if you have not done so already. Read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439). Also I would recommend to switch over to PDO instead of mysqli, because it is better and simpler.

Your PHP and SQL have problems.

- You don't seem to be connecting to the database anywhere.
- Your code is not using prepared statements, which makes it vulnerable to SQL injection.
- You can remove `exit` from your code, it doesn't do anything
- The syntax for `LIKE` is `LIKE '%string%'`, without `=`

A good example of mysqli code should look like this.

```
<?php

// report all errors. Check the error log or enable display errors in PHP config
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Always enable mysqli error reporting
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db_conx = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');
$db_conx->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

if (isset($_POST['str'])) {
    $strid = '%'. $_POST['str'] .'%';
    // prepare -> bind -> execute
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE notifications SET did_read=1 WHERE note LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $strid);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'did_read_ok';
}
```